# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable AWS Glue Pyspark

Tags: java, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to setup AWS Glue environment on my ubuntu Virtual box by following AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html).

I have done the needful like downloading aws glue libs, spark package and setting up spark home as suggested. After that, i am not able to initialize glue context and facing below error.

```
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
or 
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
```

Error:

```
TypeError          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0798793d4033> in <module>
----> 1 glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

~/aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py in __init__(self, sparkContext, **options)
     43         super(GlueContext, self).__init__(sparkContext)
     44         register(sparkContext)
---> 45         self._glue_scala_context = self._get_glue_scala_context(**options)
     46         self.create_dynamic_frame = DynamicFrameReader(self)
     47         self.write_dynamic_frame = DynamicFrameWriter(self)

~/aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py in _get_glue_scala_context(self, **options)
     64 
     65         if min_partitions is None:
---> 66             return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc())
     67         else:
     68             return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc(), min_partitions, target_partitions)

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/33

Comment: and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/25

Comment: I can see there are multiple ways to resolve in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/33

Comment: I have reproduce the issue and working on it

Answer (score 4):

Copy aws-glue-libs jar files to Spark Jar folder. it means copy jar files from \aws-glue-libs\jarsv1\ folder to \spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8\jars folder

Comment: Where to find the jars when these packages are installed within virtualenv ?

Answer (score 1):

After implementing the instructions as per given in the URL(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html).

Check if `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath`
env variables are set to `{user_path}\\aws-glue-libs-glue-{1.0/master}\\jarsv1\\*`

To verify the classpaths execute the below code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Given error is coming mainly due to the classpath issue that pointing to AWS related jar files.